# Using jQuery to test if string contains HTML markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to test if a string has html tags in it.

```
html = "<p class=\"c\">some <span>conten<b class=\"i\">t</b></span><p><p>more content</p><p><i>important</i>";
```

I would think that using either `find()` or `has()` would help me do this, but it's not working.

```
$(html).find("p") //[]
$(html).has("p")  //[]
```

And I get confusing results if I experiment.

```
$(html).has("p") //[]
$(html).has("*") //array of <p> elements and children
$(html).has("*") == true //false
$(html).has("*").length == true //false ??
```

Why can't I use any of these methods to see if my string contains HTML markup?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Both [**.has()**](http://api.jquery.com/has/) and [**.find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/) operate on the given element's children nodes. To test the element itself, use [**.is()**](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

```
$(html).is('p');   // true
$(html).is('div'); // false
$(html).is('*');   // true
```

... although I'm rather sceptical about the usefulness of the latter, as it doesn't test specifically for HTML elements. So this...

```
var someMarkup = '<foo"bar"zzz>';
$(someMarkup).is('*');
```

... is also `true`. And if you omit the last `>` in this expression, you won't even reach `is`:

```
var noHtmlJustLt = '<';
$(noHtmlJustLt).is('*'); // Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <
```

... so you have to wrap this into `try-catch` block.

---

To be honest, I'd probably solve the whole task (check whether or not a string has some rogue markup) with a different approach: escape the original text with a common trick...

```
var newHtml = $('<div></div>').html(html).text();
```

... then compare it with original `html` contents. If there's no markup symbols, they should be equal.

Comment: ended up just doing a direct string comparison

Answer (score 2):

Both [**filter()**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [**is()**](http://api.jquery.com/is/) *only* work on the root elements, so to search the entire string for tags you'd have to set it as innerHTML of another empty element, and search that with `find()`, which only works on children, hence the wrapping parent element

```
var has_p = $('<div />', {html : html}).find("p").length > 0;
```

Comment: Can you explain what's happening with the `'<div />'` and then the comma, and then the object? I'm not familiar with that syntax

Comment: It creates an empty div, and inserts the html into that div, that way all the HTML can be searched, as `filter()` and `is()` only checks the first parent node, and `find()` and `has()` only checks the children. This checks everything.

Comment: Nice approach (+1), but how exactly it's better than `var $html = $(html); var has_p = $html.is('p') || $html.find('p').length > 0?` )

Comment: @raina77ow - Anything that works is good enough, so it's not really better, but it doesn't call two methods on two references of the collection, and it looks a lot neater without the OR.

Comment: @adeneo I see. ) Yes, it looks neater indeed.